# excel utf-8 csv export and the separator

Tags: php, excel, drupal, csv, utf-8

So I did this (I use Drupal 6):

```
  while(@ob_end_clean());
  drupal_set_header("Content-type: text/csv;");
  drupal_set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
  drupal_set_header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=translations.csv");
  print chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($output, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
  exit;
```

To export a CSV of utf-8 characters. And the utf-8 characters would display properly when I import into excel.

The problem is, excel would not parse the separators, ie, the commas  would all display in one column instead of being used as a separator on file open.

Is there a way to make it so that when I open it, the commas will be used as a separator?

A line in the csv goes the following:

```
$output .= '"'.str_replace('"', '""', $id).'","'.str_replace('"', '""', $source).'","'.str_replace('"', '""', $translation) . '"';
```

I tried using tabs \t instead of commas as separators but the same thing would happen, ie. the tabs will not be used as separator on file open

Comment: Try using a tab again, but writing UTF-16LE line by line, that's the default separator that Excel uses unless you explicity use the import feature within excel... and why can't you use fputcsv()?

Comment: I did...I replaced the , with \t and it didn't work excel would instead display a whole bunch of \t's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use comma as default CSV separator, one needs to change corresponding Windows Regional Settings option:

> Go to the Control Panel --> Regional and Language Options (or Date,
>   Time and Regional Options --> Regional and Language Option on some
>   machines) --> click the Customize button. In the dialog box that opens
>   you will see and option for "**List separator**" in which you can change
>   the comma to a different character --> click Apply then Ok and then
>   Apply again.

Please note the following:

1. This setting is used for BOTH CSV import and export by default.
2. You should open CSV files using `File > Open`, NOT `Data > Import External Data > Import Data...`, or simply double-click any CSV in Explorer, and it will be opened in Excel with default separator applied.

Read more:

- http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=134498
- https://superuser.com/a/298177/187330

Comment: The question says "The problem is, excel would not parse the separators, ie, the commas would all display in one column instead of being used as a separator on file open. Is there a way to make it so that when I open it, the commas will be used as a separator?" which shows `File > Open` is not working. That is why I suggested using the wizard to test it and try different delimiters because it allows you to change it in there too.

Comment: @Pricey The question is: "Is there a way to make it so that when I open it, the commas will be used as a separator?" - and my answer suits it. I DO agree your answer is more wide, but I assume the problem is "I'd like to open CSVs with no additional actions". Your answer better suits a question like: "Please advice how to open / import CSVs and say Excel which char is used as a separator".

Comment: Yea I agree that if they don't have a comma as their default regional list separator already then the option is there to change the regional list separator but they may not want to make that change, it depends on the use case which is unknown at the moment. My comment was related more to your 2nd point and that the import options in Excel shouldn't be ignored just yet.

Comment: @Pricey sure our answers covered all the aspects of CSV import for the given case) Now it's up to asker to decide which suits him better. Anyway, got my upvote for useful suggestion!)

Answer (score 1):

If your using Excel 2007 then if you open Excel first, then you can go to the `Data` tab and then select `From Text`

Select your .csv file in the explorer browser and then the text wizard should appear. This gives you more steps and options to control what it is looking for with regards to breaking up the columns etc.

Older version of Excel also support it but I can't be certain its in the same place, I think it is though.

Try that wizard and see how if it sorts your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Unicode support from Excel with x-separated-values, use tab-separated UTF-16 Little-Endian (what Excel generates when you **Save As...** > **Unicode Text (*.txt)**).

If you don't, you get issues like what you're experiencing.

See: [Excel and Unicode](http://www.herongyang.com/Unicode/Excel-Using-Microsoft-Excel-as-Unicode-Text-Editor.html)